# pdflatex and gnuplot's epslatex

Tags: pdftex, input, gnuplot, postscript, epslatex

I'm having some trouble trying to use gnuplot's epslatex terminal in a tex document to be compiled with pdflatex. The figure appears too big in the final pdf, and the axis' tics are not in math mode, even though I used `set format '$ %g $'`. I have been playing around with the plot's size too, but I achieved pretty much nothing.

Here is the result using png:
[image: Pdf from png]

And here the result using epslatex:
[image: Pdf from epslatex]

Here is a minimal working example for the tex file (commented part to obtain the png version):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,pdf]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{figure.png}
\input{figure.tex}
\caption{Some text.}
\label{something}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And here the gnuplot script (again, commented part for png):

```
set xlabel 'x label'
set ylabel 'y label'

f(x)=a*(1-exp(-k*x))

fit f(x) 'data.dat' via a, k

#set term pngcairo size 2000,1500
#set termoption font ',35'
#set output 'figure.png'
set term epslatex size 10cm,6cm
set output 'figure.tex'
set format '$%g$'
unset key
set samples 10000
set xrange [0:11]

plot 'data.dat' w p pt 7 ps 4 lc rgb 'black', f(x) lw 4 lc rgb 'red'
```

Also, the file data.dat, for completeness' sake:

```
1   1
2   1.64
3   2.4
5   3.28
10  5.6.
```

I don't know if this question should be here because it may be a gnuplot issue rather than a pdflatex issue, but anyway, help will be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Why not just use `pgfplots` instead?

Comment: I didn't know this one, thanks for suggesting it! I'll give it a try, although I'd still want to find out how to use `epslatex`.

Comment: Are you aware of the TikZ terminal?
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/gnuplot-tikz-terminal/

Comment: No I was not! This is pretty good as well, the plot is working very nicely! Thanks a lot!Although it took quite a bit to compile with pdflatex, considering that the document consisted only of the figure... I guess that's the price to pay for quality :D

Comment: It works with `set terminal epslatex size 10cm,6cm color standalone`, then `pdflatex figure.tex` and then `\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{figure.pdf}`, which is fast because it compiles the graph only once.

Comment: If I do that (compile `figure.tex` beforehand and use `\includegraphics{ ... .pdf}` instead of `\input{ ... .tex}`) the figure has the right size, but then there are no axis titles or tics! This is strange, because the `\put{ ... }` are there in the .tex generated by `gnuplot`... I don't know why `pdflatex` is not using them, or maybe I didn't understand your instructions

Comment: It worked here right out of the box with `epslatex`. You can check the size  by putting `\rule{10cm}{1pt}\\ ` before `\input{figure.tex}`. The size includes the space for the label and some space around, not just the graph. Plot file: `set format` only sets the format for the numbers on the axis. This works and can be checked with e.g. `set format '$%ga$'`. To get the labels in math mode you can use e.g. `set xlabel '$x$ label`. Caution: if the png file still exists, it will be included instead of the eps file. You can also use `set term cairolatex pdf size ...` to get a pdf instead of eps.

Comment: Ok, the problem was, as Mike says, having the png file in the folder. I do not understand why this happens, but it does.

Comment: Alright, I looked at the tex file from gnuplot and I figured it out. The problem is that both the eps and the png file have the same name, and the tex file created by `gnuplot` does `\includegraphics{figure}` without specifying an extension. If I either erase the png or modify the tex to `\includegraphics{figure.eps}`, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mike stated in the comments, if the png file generated by `gnuplot` is at the folder when `pdflatex` is run, it will use the png file instead of the eps.

I am writing this only so I can mark the question as closed.

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
\input{figure.tex}
```

you better use:

```
\resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{\input{figure.tex}}
```

Comment: That was not the problem, although I can see why you would say this. My problem was that I used pngcairo as ``gnuplot``'s output before trying ``epslatex``. The tex file generated by epslatex specifies no extension in the ``\includegraphics`` statement, so it will use the existing png instead of the eps file generated by ``gnuplot`` for some reason.